# Add a /directory after a variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `profile.php?id=` page, I turn it into `profile/id` with this RewriteRule `RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9-\/]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`

Right now I'm trying to set a page to contact the user so I create a `contact-profile.php?id=`

I want to make an URL like that `profile/user-id/contact` but I'm stuck.
I tried to do this `RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9-\/]+)/?$/contact contact-profil.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` but it doesn't work. The problem is that I don't know how to pass this fake `/directory` after my `/user-id` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/contact$ contact-profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: what is the required url and what is the original url please write in comments by mentioning.

Comment: The original URL is `contact-profile.php?id=user-id-123` and I'd like to use the `profile.php?id=user-id-123` as contact page like that `profile/user-id-123/contact`

Comment: is this url `contact-profile.php?id=$1` is right and at right place?

Comment: I'm redirected as written in my script in case of error.  
I also tried `RewriteRule ^profile/contact/([A-Za-z0-9-\/]+)/?$ contact-profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` I putted the /contact before the variable and it doesn't work too. It's strange, when I use a slash it doesn't work with this rule but when I put `^profile-contact......` it works

Comment: is this url `contact-profile.php?id=user-id-123` working fine without applying any rule? and please comment out other rules if any because I've tested it according to your need and it is working for me.

Comment: Yeah, without the rewrite rule the URL is fully working